# Dijkstra's isn't making changes to previous node array

Tags: java, dijkstra

Using Dijkstra's for route finding, but every time i run the algorithm, i end up not making changes to the previous node array.

```
public static int[] findRoute(Web m, int s)
{
    final int[] dist = new int[m.edges.length];         //shortest known dist from s
    final int[] pred = new int[m.edges.length];     //previous node in path
    final boolean[] visited = new boolean[m.edges.length];  //all start as false

    //sets each distance to max, until measured
    for(int i = 0; i < dist.length; i++)
    {  
        dist[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    dist[s] = 0; //distance to self is 0 always

    for(int i = 0; i < dist.length; i++)
    {
        int next = minVertex (dist, visited);
        visited[next] = true;
        //shortest path to next is dist[next] and via pred[next]
        //counts roads that are connected
        int c = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < m.edges[next].length; j++)
        {
            if(m.edges[next][j] > 0) c++;
        }
        //create array to hold connected road indexes
        int[] n = new int[c];
        //reset c
        c = 0;
        //loop to fill n with indexes of neighbors
        for(int j = 0; j < m.edges[next].length; j++)
            {if(m.edges[next][j]>0) n[c++] = j;}
        for(int j = 0; j < n.length; j++){
            final int v = n[j];
            final int d = dist[next] + m.edges[next][v];
            if (dist[v] > d) {
                dist[v] = d;
                pred[v] = next;
            }
        }
    }
    return pred; //ignore pred[s] == 0
}
```

Web class is just a 2D array that holds the distances from node to node if there is a connection. After some testing, it seems like pred isn't updating beyond the initial round. How can i change it to properly make updates to the pred array? This is my 1st time attempting to use the algorithm, I've read through a bundle of pseudocode for it, but I haven't been able to figure out where i went wrong. Currently when i try to print a path, i just get the destination, followed by node 0 infinitely.

minVertex

```
private static int minVertex(int[] dist, boolean[] v)
{
    int x = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int y = -1; //graph not connected or no unvisited
    for(int i = 0; i < dist.length; i++)
    {
        if(!v[i] && dist[i] < x) 
        {
            y = i;
            x = dist[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(y);
    return y;
}
```

Edges and intersections

- Intersection 1: X = 0, Y = -1
- Intersection 2: X = 0, Y = 0
- Intersection 3: X = 1, Y = 0
- Intersection 4: X = 1, Y = 3
- Intersection 5: X = 0, Y = 3
- Intersection 6: X = 2, Y = 3

edges are all 500 long, edges are

- i2-i1
- i1-i2
- i2-i3
- i3-i4
- i4-i5
- i5-i2
- i2-i5
- i6-i4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you put in your answer is a correct implementation of O(V^2) array Dijkstra. Based on your description of the issue, I believe the problem is that in your minVertex() code (which you ddin't provide), you need to check if the vertex is visited and only return the minimum distance among non-visited vertices.

Let me know if this fixes the problem. If not, could you please edit your question to provide the rest of your code?

Comment: Added minVertex. Unless I'm misreading or just dumb, which is a possibility, I'm checking that its not visited and distance is less than Integer.maxvalue, Should I just be looking at not visited?

Comment: That's fine, then. I notice you have a debugging line in `minVertex()` that prints `y`. Can you show me the output of this line when you're running `findRoute()`, as well as the adjacency matrix `m.edges` that you're running it on?

Comment: Right now, it's returning 0, then -1 and I get an index out of bounds at visited[next] = true; There are about 90 nodes with 260 edges, though i suppose i can make a smaller set to test with

Comment: Changed it to have 6 nodes and 8 edges, editing main question to give the data more readability

Comment: Okay, is it still giving you the same error with your smaller graph? What do the x and y values for each intersection mean?

Comment: Sorry for my delayed replies, thanksgiving festivities and so on. The x and y are just the coordinates, and yes, I get the same results, the y printouts from minVertex are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that helps narrow down the problem! I've read over your Dijkstra implementation a few times now, but I really can't see any problems the code you provided. Can you check for me if your graph `Web m` is correct? Perhaps you accidentally made it one-indexed? Just run this code for me: `for (int i = 0; i < m.edges.length; i++) { System.out.println(m.edges[0][i]); }`.

Comment: 500
0
0
0
0
0
0

So it looks like its creating to the proper length, and only filling in 1 edge. I ran it with replacing the edges[0] to edges[1], i only printed a 500 in the 2nd slot, otherwise 0's. Ill look more in to my web length assignment, see if that helps.

Comment: Awesome, so the problem wasn't in that method after all! Let me know if I can be of any more help.

Comment: Alright, fixed it. Apparently i wasnt making sure i added edges properly, my edges have the start and end locations as part of a class, and i was grabbing the start locations twice. After that, everything fell in to place and it works perfectly well now. Thanks for telling me where to look!